# Connecting to RabbitMQ cluster with Java client

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

Imagine that we have RabbitMQ cluster with several nodes. I have some general knowledge how HA in RabbitMQ cluster works, but there are multiple problems and associated questions that trouble me.

**How does inter-node connection works**

I know that every queue is bound to one node for which it retains a `master` status and can be replicated across multiple nodes. Clients talks only to the `master` queue. I have read that RabbitMQ node "redirects" connection to another node should any client try to work with `slave` queue. What does the term `redirects` mean?

- Is this an inter-node communication? Like is this completely transparent to the client and nodes communicate on behind like in interconnect fashion?
- Or is client notified about master node and is a new connection open for that reason? Like does the Java client open a new connection with that node to perform all the communication through that?

This leads to another question

**Can client open new connection to unknown node**

Because I know that `ConnectionFactory` can be configured with a list of Rabbit nodes. If there is a mechanism that tells the client that new connection should be open then my question is whether this has to be a "known connection" listed in the list of known Rabbit nodes given to the `ConnectionFactory`

I have read several articles about load balancing that keeps topology metadata in a special database and uses smart routing according to the data, but I find that quite complicated to implement for consumers and extremely complicated for producers (because this would work only for direct exchanges).

To summarize my question:

Does AMQP Java client open new connections for unknown nodes and does it use those connections for future communication with nodes where appropriate queue resides? That means if client contacts `NODE A` for `QUEUE X` and it gets the information that it should contact `NODE B`, will it open a new connection to `NODE B`. And will that client use this connection to `NODE B` for each access to `QUEUE X`? Because in that case, I find load balancing for consumers obsolete.

Or am I missing something?